# Conversion to array of multiple select in PHP

Tags: php, multiple-select

In my local system I can safely send the values of a multiple select box by ending the name of the select with a couple brackets [ ]. Then PHP will deal with the parameters sent, and treat the values of the select box as an array in the `$_REQUEST` (or `$_GET`, or `$_POST`)

I thought that behaviour was from the beginning, but it doesn't work this way in another system (which, unfortunately, **I don't know any of its particularities** like the PHP version), and when you try to access the multiple values from the `$_REQUEST`, it won't get an array, but only the last selected value.

So, my question is: Does anyone know from which version of PHP is performed this "arrayfication" of multiple same name values? Or maybe I'm wrong?

Here a test (that is working in my local, but not in the other (presumably) older system:

```
<?php
echo "Query string: ", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "<br>";
echo '$_GET: ';
print_r($_GET);
echo "<br><br>";
?>

<form method="get" role="form">
    <select name="multi[]" multiple><!--onchange="setmail(this)"-->
        <option value="1">value 1</option>
        <option value="2">value 2</option>
        <option value="3">value 3</option>
        <option value="4">value 4</option>
        <option value="5">value 5</option>
        <option value="6">value 6</option>
        <option value="7">value 7</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

and the result after checking two options and hitting send in my local:

> Query string: multi%5B%5D=1&multi%5B%5D=2
>
> $_GET: Array ( [multi] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) )

and in the other system:

> Query string: multi%5B%5D=1&multi%5B%5D=2
>
> $_GET: Array ( [multi%5B%5D] => 2)

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, you can always get them individually and loop through them as you add the elements in a locally created array.

Comment: Can you add a piece of html with this select and also what do you have in $_REQUEST at all?

Comment: I think it's not an PHP-Problem but an internally convertion by your server-software (since it's URL-encoded). Which software runs your local environment on and which software does the server run on?

Comment: On this older system, what browser/version or backend/version is being used? It may also be possible that this is a SysOps question?

Comment: @Christian I'm really sorry, but as I stated in the question, I don't know any of the particularities of that system. Mine is working with PHP 5.5.6, but that's not relevant since my system work flawlessly as expected.

Comment: rule of thumb: Never use $_REQUEST . but i bet your problem is that your local system and the remote server has a different request_order =??? in php.ini . -- http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order